# Date data from Text file to date time in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am using one flat file as source which have couple of columns belong to Date format and I have placed all the data into the SQL Server table which predefined.

Example:-

Flat file

```
CaseNO|CaseType|CDate
1     |ORG     |1\12\2012
2     |PGD     |3\3\2011
```

here when I check it with data viewer, Its looks like 2012-12-1 00:00:00.0000000. but the OLE DB connection creates the following errors.

```
[OLE DB Destination [7546]] Error: There was an error with input column 
"CDate" (8799) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (7559). The column status
returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
```

Please guide me...Appreciated your help.

343

Comment: My first guess would be one of the records has a bad value. You could try just importing the first few rows to make sure it isn't a generic issue.

Comment: What is datatype of column for CDate in destination table and datatype of CDate id data flow?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of the backslashes. Try replacing "\" with "/" before casting.

This could also be a date format issue. Depending on settings like collation, "1/2/2012" could be interpretted as January 2 or February 1. This wouldn't cause a problem, however something like "1/31/2012" could cause a type conversion error with the wrong collation because there isn't a month 31.

Comment: Thanks for yr help Bian...I think this is the problem , the thing is still now there is no data into my destination table and I tries to uploads the flat files data into it. In flat file the date in mm-dd-yy format where I checked with other tables they have (2012-09-14 14:01:18.593) yy-dd-mm hh.mm.ss.ms....but could you please tell me how I can change it to desired format?

Comment: All you have to do is cast the value to datetime. Add a derived column in between the source and the destination. Make the derived column name CDateTime and paste (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)REPLACE(CDate,"\\","/") in as the expression value. Now map CDateTime to the appropriate column in the OLE DB Destination.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already staged the data into in the sql server table. Use the SQL command instead of selecting the the table in OLEDB source. Write query as follows and map to destination.

SELECT Id,CaseType,convert(datetime,CDATE,101) as Cdate from

If you directly loading using the flat file to the target table. you should parse it using the derived column transformation to mention format[dd/mm/yyyy] and convert to datatime.

Thanks,
Gowdhaman